# vue js css modules are giving the same names to elements in each rendering

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, css-modules, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

I am working on a vue project and I made CSS as `modules` so that I can assign different class names to different elements.

But the component containing the CSS module is rendering multiple times like:

```html
     <ButtonGroup
      v-for="(i, index) in buttons"
      :key="index"
      :label="i.label"
      :buttons="i.names"
      class="mt-3"
    ></ButtonGroup>
```

the button group component renders the buttons like this

```html
 <button
        v-for="(i, index) in buttons"
        :key="index"
        type="button"
        @click="changeClass"
        class="btn"
        :class="[index < 1 ? [$style.active, $style.btnNew] : [$style.btnNew]]"
      >
        {{ i }}
      </button>
```

It assigns class names like

```
src-components-inputs-buttonGroup---active---PEcjn src-components-inputs-buttonGroup---btn-new---3RluI
```

But I want different class names in each rendering of same component

Comment: What you want is not possible. Class names are generated at build time (on your machine), components are rendered at runtime (in client's browser). Why would you want such thing anyway? Maybe you should describe in detail what you are trying to accomplish....

Comment: actually what i am doing is creating dynamic button groups for selecting options...
its design requirement.
so when i used the same component on multiple places with same class names...
it just mix all the elements up.

Comment: Ok, I still don't see why would "dynamic button groups for selecting options" required different CSS classes for each group...